# Primefaces no scrolls page

Tags: jsf, layout, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to create little web application in primefaces and have a problem. My is made like combination of layouts and layoutunits inside each other and I want to make it independent of client screen size, so it will load with all the content viewable. But it just hide images and text instead of making page longer in browser. Sorry for my bad English skills.

Comment: I mean like how to replace little scrollbars from layoutunits and layouts with one global scrollbar for webpage and so all the content in layouts will be fullsized in any screen size

Comment: Please go with some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe try to give the layoutunits overflow:visible. Or fixed heights